# JBoss as client 5.1.0.GA repository missing

Tags: jboss, maven, client, repository

Just recently I was creating new maven project on new computer and it seams that the dependency for jboss as client isn't available anymore:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.jbossas</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-as-client</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0.GA</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

And the repository resource is:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jboss-maven2</id>
        <url>http://repository.jboss.com/maven2</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Is there any new repository url, because I can not download any dependency since this site is broken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [this](http://community.jboss.org/en/build/blog/2010/04/20/announcement--new-maven-repository-infrastructure) post.  JBoss Maven repository has been migrated to a new Nexus repository.  Old repo has been kept for a while, but it looks like they revoked public access in the meanwhile.

See the documentation for details, but you'll probably need the new repo url https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public which does contain your required artifact.

Comment: What's the error you're getting?  When I try it in an empty project without a settings.xml it doesn't work with the repo from your question (Access Denied).  When I change the url, it works just fine.

Comment: I was sharing my project with my associates, and it didn't work for them. Now I created new project with brand new maven2 installation, and now it's downloading jars to repository. Thanks.

Comment: Now again an error. It seams that the now repository is searching some of his dependencies in old repository              [http://repository.jboss.com/maven2](http://repository.jboss.com/maven2). It worked today, but now it's not.

Comment: Which dependency cannot be found?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue with a project that depends on jboss-as-client:5.1.0.GA.

First, you can search the [JBoss Nexus Maven repository](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/index.html#welcome) for the artifact that is missing.  Clicking on it will show you what repository it is in (such as JBoss Thirdparty Releases).  Then you can [view the list of JBoss repositories](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/index.html#view-repositories) to get the URL for the repository you need.  I had to add the JBoss Releases, JBoss Deprecated, and JBoss Thirdparty repositories.